# Why react-router does not display correct component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I enter `localhost:8080` in my browser it displays App.js component. But when I navigate to `localhost:8080/#/hello` it displays same App.js component instead of hello.js. localhost:8080/hello show "can not get localhost:8080/hello" . What is the problem with my code? I am using webpack and babel in my App.

```
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './public/store/store';
import App from './public/Components/App';
import Hello from './public/Components/hello';
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

//import './index.css'


render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
   <div>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/hello" component={Hello}/>
   </div>
  </Router>
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('root')
)


//App.js
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
      <div>
          <h1>React Js.</h1>
      </div>
  );
 }
}


//hello.js

import React from 'react';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
      <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to clarify the "localhost:8080/hello display can not get localhost:8080/hello"? It's totally unclear. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things happening here, let me try to explain what's going wrong and how you can fix them.

> http://localhost:8080/#/hello it displays the same App.js component instead of hello.js.

Because you are using `BrowserRouter` instead of HashRouter (an older version, # is not working). The browser reads only the first part of your URL which is `http://localhost:8080/`. The `#` is similar when you route to a section of a page using the following.
`<a href="#projects">Goto projects</a>`

The above keeps the user on the same page but scrolls to the section `<div id="projects"></div>`

Don't use this, if your are using React Router V4 it's not what you are looking for.

> http://localhost:8080/hello displays cannot get http://localhost:8080/hello

You probably don't have a dev server running that supports front-end routing. If you don't, basically what is happening is that by pressing enter you tell the SERVER to serve you page, `http://localhost:8080/hello`. You don't want this, the server should be passive here and not serve you any other page then your main index.html. So, instead, you want the server to give you `http://localhost:8080` and by doing so, it loads your main index.html and scripts, then react takes over, react-router checks the url and it then renders you the /hello route with the `Hello` component.

In order to achieve this make sure you have `webpack-dev-server` installed. You can do this by typing the following in the command line.
`npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

Then add the following to your package.json

```
devServer: {
  publicPath: '/',
  historyApiFallback: true
}
// add the below line to the scripts section
  "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server"
```

This basically tells the dev-server to re-route all requests to index.html, so react-router takes care of the routing. [Here's more on Webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback).

Then in your terminal run `npm run start:dev` to start the development server.

I hope this all makes sense and with these guidelines you're able to make your code work. If not let me know ;)

**NOTE:** Alex has a good point as well. React Router v4 renders all routes that match. So, if the path is `http://localhost:8080/hello`
`/` and `/hallo` both match and will render. If you only want to render one, use `exact` as Alex mentions, or wrap your routes in a `<Switch>` component.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  <Route path="/hello" component={Hello}/>
</Switch>
```

Here's what the [react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) say.

> Renders the first child  or  that matches the location

**UPDATE:**
After the OP uploaded a repo with the problem, the following was corrected to make the routes work. If anyone is interested, [the fixed project is on GitHub](https://github.com/rscheffers82/express-react-router-example).

Main points to make the project work:

- Use `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router`
- Tell Express route all incoming traffic to index.html `app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));`
- Use `<Switch>` and `<Route>` components to setup the routes as described in the question. [See code here](https://github.com/rscheffers82/express-react-router-example/blob/master/index.js#L37-L41).

Comment: Hi Vikas, it's really hard for me to get an idea of what's not working and why. Can you include your package.json into your question. Even better would be if you can place your repo on GitHub so that I can have a look at the full setup. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Scheffers this is github link  https://github.com/vikas336/ReactFullstack tell me where I am wrong in github code.

Comment: Wow, your setup was completely different from the details in your question. Your serving files using NodeJS and Express, no wonder things weren't working. I've made a few adjustments to your server and include three routes in the frontend. Repo with my changes is at [Express React Router example](https://github.com/rscheffers82/express-react-router-example) on GitHub. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Hi Scheffers ,  for resolving my problem now it is working. Sorry for giving you different Repo code because i forget to update it.

Comment: No problem, this can happen and for me, it was a good challenge. I haven't seen a Webpack / NodeJS setup like this before, so learned something new myself when fixing it. I"ll update my answer with the main things I've adjusted. Would you mind marking my answer as accepted? That'll help others to see we came to a conclusion. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Scheffers  thanks but currently don't able to mark useful due to I have reputation less than 15.

Comment: I've added the Updated section to my answer with the main points I fixed in the project. No need to upvote. Check the V beside my answer to mark it as accepted. That's what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `exact` directive:

`<Route exact path="/" component={App} />`

See API doc: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool